# C# - Remote control a PC without port-forwaring (Like TeamViewer)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

**EDIT**

I figured out what the problem was, but now I faced an other. I want to remote control 1 PC from an other PC, that part works, but you have to port forward the port. Is it possible to connect like TeamViewer? So I bypass the firewall and don't have to port forward? If yes, how? If someone could help me out it would be pretty awesome :)

- Bram

**ORIGINAL POST**

I made a code so you can control a computer from an other computer. The only problem is that it doesn't work for computers outside of your own network (Maybe I connected the wrong IP? I tried the IPv4 of the guy and the IP from [WhatIsMyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) ). How can I make this work for outside my network?

Here is the server class(I removed a lot of code, because it didn't make sense)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

        private const int MOUSE_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        private const int MOUSE_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        private const int MOUSE_RIGTDOWN = 0x08;
        private const int MOUSE_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

        private TcpListener listener;
        private Socket mainSocket;
        private int port;
        private Stream s;
        private Thread eventWatcher;
        private int imageDelay;
        string connString;
        string connToString;
        string db;
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlCommand command2;
        MySqlCommand command3;
        MySqlCommand command4;

        MySqlConnection connection = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            port = 1338;
            imageDelay = 1000;
        }
        public Form1(int p)
        {
            port = p;
            imageDelay = 1000;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(getIP());
            startConnection();

            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command2 = connection.CreateCommand();
            command3 = connection.CreateCommand();
            command4 = connection.CreateCommand();
            MessageBox.Show(connString);
            MessageBox.Show(db);

            this.Hide();
            port = 1338;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    startListening();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        public void startListening()
        {
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(port);
                listener.Start();
                mainSocket = listener.AcceptSocket();
                s = new NetworkStream(mainSocket);
                eventWatcher = new Thread(new ThreadStart(waitForKeys));
                eventWatcher.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    Bitmap screeny = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    Graphics theShot = Graphics.FromImage(screeny);
                    theShot.ScaleTransform(.25F, .25F);
                    theShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                    BinaryFormatter bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bFormat.Serialize(s, screeny);
                    Thread.Sleep(imageDelay);
                    theShot.Dispose();
                    screeny.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (mainSocket.IsBound)
                    mainSocket.Close();
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.Stop();
            }
        }

        private static void trigger(IAsyncResult i) { }
```

And the client code(Again, removed a lot):

```
    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private static string response;

        private Stream stream;
        private StreamWriter eventSender;
        private Thread theThread;
        private TcpClient client;
        private Form1 mForm;
        private int resolutionX;
        private int resolutionY;
        //private int sendDelay = 250;
        //private Thread delayThread;
        public bool sendKeysAndMouse = false;

        private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Form2(TcpClient s, Form1 callingForm)
        {
            client = s;
            mForm = callingForm;
            InitializeComponent();
            theThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startRead));
            theThread.Start();
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (theThread.IsAlive)
                theThread.Abort();
            mForm.form2Closed();
        }
        private void startRead()
        {
            try
            {
                stream = client.GetStream();
                eventSender = new StreamWriter(stream);
                while (true)
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
                    Bitmap inImage = bFormat.Deserialize(stream) as Bitmap;
                    resolutionX = inImage.Width;
                    resolutionY = inImage.Height;
                    theImage.Image = (Image)inImage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            /*try
            {
                Image theDesktop;
                stream = client.GetStream();
                theDesktop.Save(stream,new ImageFormat(
                while (true)
                {
                    while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) > 0)
                        theDesktop.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    if(theDesktop != null) {
                        theDesktop.
                        theImage.Image = temp;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception gay) { }*/
        }

        private void Form2_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        private void theImage_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sendKeysAndMouse)
                return;
            eventSender.Write("LCLICK\n");
            eventSender.Flush();
        }

        private void theImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sendKeysAndMouse)
                return;
            eventSender.Write("LDOWN\n");
            eventSender.Flush();
        }

        private void theImage_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!sendKeysAndMouse)
                return;
            eventSender.Write("LUP\n");
            eventSender.Flush();
        }

        private void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;

                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        response = state.sb.ToString();
                    }
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me, or explain me what I'm doing wrong and how I can make it work.

Comment: I suspect you are having network connectivity issues, rather than a code problem. There is probably a firewall between you and the host PC and/or it does not have an IP address you can route to.

Comment: You may need to forward the TCP port or allow it through your firewall. Applications like UltraVNC often have these kinds of problems.

Comment: So, what IP do I need to connect? The IP from WhatIsMyIP.com? Or the IPv4?

Comment: Please try to narrow down your problem and not make us read all of that code. Most of that code has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Likely the WhatIsMyIP.com IP, (which is also probably IPv4). The other computers local address is not important, other than he needs to set up port forwarding on his router to it. At this point, you may want to ask this question (sans code) on Server Fault if you can't find an existing one there.

Comment: How does e.g Team Viewer this? They don't need a port forwarded port. Is this also possible for my application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way Team Viewer does this is there is a 3rd computer in the interaction. Team Viewer has a public server on the internet that both you and the person you are connecting to talk to and all it does is act as a bridge forwarding incoming messages from one end to the other end. Now both ends have outbound connections and don't need port forwarding.

To do the same with your system you would need to set up, host (pay for), and maintain a public server on the internet that all users of your program would talk to and act as the bridge for communications.

The steps are like this:

1. Computer1 opens a outbound connection to Server1 and keeps it open, they can now talk back and forth without port porwarding.
2. Computer2 opens a outbound connection to Server1 and keeps it open, they can now talk back and forth without port forwarding.
3. Computer1 sends a message to Server1 that says "Forward the following to Computer2"
4. Server1 uses the open connection from step 2 that Computer2 initiated to forward the message.
5. When Computer2 wants to reply it sends a message to Server1 that says "Forward the following to Computer1"
6. Server1 uses the open connection from step 1 that Computer1 initiated to forward the message.

Comment: So, if I'm right about this, you would send something to a webserver, the webserver sends a signal to the other pc and the other way around?

Comment: Thanks. I think I kinda understand it now. But, how is Server1 able to connect to Computer2 and send it a message?

Comment: Computer2 initiated the connection to Server1 when the program started up, Computer1 then keeps the connection open (re-connecting in the event of a disconnect) listening for new messages. Server1 uses that opened connection to send the messages on.

Comment: That Computer1 in my previous comment should have been Computer2

Comment: Could you please help me to develop the same app to control another PC ... thanx in advance.